# What do you call duties that take place at a specific time each week?

Tags: word-request, time

I want to set up a meeting with someone in the next few weeks. I want to write something like this:

**My only fixed-time duty in the next few weeks is a weekly Monday meeting at 4 pm.**

I want to express that the only fixed appointments I have are those on Monday. However I could not confirm that my usage of 'fixed-time duty' is correct here. Is it correct and what are the alternatives?

*Remark.* This question is somewhat difficult to google because you get a lot of pages referring to a "fixed-term" as in "a fixed-term contract", which has a  meaning different from the one I am looking for.

Comment: The word **duty** doesn't feel 100% here, because it means something like "a task to be accomplished".  I guess you could say something like "His only duty was to attend a meeting once a week", but you wouldn't normally say that "a meeting" = "a duty".

Comment: "The only _regular commitment_ I have is..."

Comment: **scheduled appointments** are a Monday meeting at [time].

Comment: Thanks for the comments, they are really helpful!